# Is there a way to construct lazy sequences in Python?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, lazy-sequences, generator-expression

There is a Django view that loads `Member` objects from the database with a certain filter.

Now I need to change this logic to **present a specific `Member` first, and let the rest follow in their natural order**.

The most straightforward way is to execute the query right away, get a list, remove and insert the item at the beginning. However I am most curious **if there is still any way to make use of `QuerySet`'s lazy nature**.

In C#, I would write:

```
IEnumerable<Member> members = db.Members; // db.Members is lazy
members = Enumerable.Union( // construct a lazy sequence that traverses its arguments
    new [] { specificMember },
    members.Where(m => m != specificMember)
);
```

As a loop would go through `members`, it would first get `specificMember` and then use **whatever lazy loading logic original `db.Members` used**.

Is there a way to do the same in Django and Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain`. Something like:

```
import itertools
original_members = .... # get an iterator of the data
members = itertools.chain([specific_member], original_members)
```

The chain function returns an iterator. The iterator starts by returning the value from the sequence in the first parameter, which is a single-element list containing specific_member. Then it starts returning the values from `original_members`, which I assume is a lazy sequence.

Comment: This is amazing. Precisely what I was looking for but didn't know the name. Thanks.